# aligning image-link with text disables link

Tags: html, css

I have an image and a set of links I am trying to bottom align on a page.

I made an example here http://bootply.com/109411

Basically when I have them aligned, the image no longer acts like a link.

If I remove either `position: relative;` from `#static-links` or `height: 100px;` from `.fixedheight` the image now acts like a link, but the contents are no longer aligned.

I am wondering why this happens, and how I can get the contents bottom-aligned without breaking the image link.

Thanks

Comment: *edit* I asked for example code, but you did provide it. The link wasn't loading for me so I assumed it was a personal site. Sorry.

@Luis, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @badAdviceGuy he did provide an example link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that because the #static-links div is positioned relatively, it creates a full-width layer that obscures the logo/link element behind it. Effectively, the link still works, but your cursor can't touch it because #static-links is hiding it.

Try add position: relative (and maybe "z-index: 1") to the div that wraps your logo/link. This will bring it one layer above the #static-links and make it clickable.